# Drop Down List With Search Button In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a customer model with the following collection:

```
@doctors =  Customer.joins(:user).where(users: {role: User.roles[:doctor]})
```

which joins the user table and customer tables where user role is "doctor".

In my Customers index view currently I am listing all the customers, now I want to add a search filter using a Drop down list with a search button, where the list contains the first name of the Doctors. If I press the search button it should show only customers created by that particular doctor selected from the drop down list.

**1.** How to add a drop down list with search button which displays only first names of doctors ?

---

**2.** How to filter my customers listing when I select a particular doctor from the drop down and click on search button ?

---

```html
<div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><b>Search By Dr.</b></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="caret"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

              <li><a href="#">List All Customers</a></li>
            <% @practices.each do |practice| %>
              <li><a href="#">Dr.<%= practice.firstname %></a></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The above is the code that I am currently using, but is it correct way of Rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can simply use the following tag in your rails view:

   `<%= select("doctor", "firstname", @doctors.all.collect(&:firstname)) %>`
2. Then in your controller you'd have something like this:

   `def index
     if params[:doctor]
        @customers = Customer.joins(:user).where(users: {role: User.roles[:doctor]}, firstname: params[:doctor][:firstname].downcase)
     else
        @customers = Customer.all
     end
   end`

Comment: @doctors =  Customer.joins(:user).where(users: {role: User.roles[:doctor]})  Now what to do in    view, I dont understand the rails guide. I just want to list all doctors :firstname as drop down  list items, then a search or selecting any of the dropdown item must show all customers created by that doctor id.

Comment: Is that link clearer? https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/rails-4-dropdown-menu-with-collection_select/
I try to get you to understand how it works rather than writing the code for you :P

Comment: thank you , I still confused as I am a total beginner. I need the drop down with doctors first name. Clicking on it must filter the customers under that particular doctor.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1:

you can do this task using JS I will recommend you to use one of these jquery plugins for search bars [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) and [Chosen](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).

My personal experience with select2 is impressive.

it loads data via ajax and cache as well to avoid repeat calls. Its GUI give u a Google like feel. read its documentation and use it.

Answer 2:

select2 also give u events like `change`  so u can make another ajax call to load filterd customers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have to implement it using pure ruby on rails itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this auto_complete rails. Have a look on 
    http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association

Thanks